# How do I make hotkeys in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with pygame and I want to add a hotkey to close the game. Right now I am using:

```
keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

# Hotkey for exiting game. CTRL + SHIFT + Q
if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LCTRL] and keys_pressed[pygame.K_LSHIFT] and keys_pressed[pygame.K_q]:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

This works in closing the game but if I press other keys with it (Ex/ CTRL + SHIFT + L + Q), it also closes the game. Is there a way I can fix this and have it only work if my desired keys are pressed and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're handling `KEYDOWN` or `KEYUP` [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html), the event object has a bit field attribute called `mod` that will tell you which other [modifier keys](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#key-modifiers-label) are pressed.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
pygame.init()

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(f"Key {pygame.key.name(event.key)} pressed")
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                if event.mod & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and event.mod & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:      
                    print("Hotkey Exit!")
                    run = False       
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            print(f"Key {pygame.key.name(event.key)} released")

    screen.fill(pygame.Color("grey"))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit to 60 FPS

pygame.quit()
```

When running the code and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> you'll see the following on the console:

```
$ python3.9 -i pyg_simple_hotkey.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Key left ctrl pressed
Key left shift pressed
Key q pressed
Hotkey Exit!
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count the total number of keys pressed and include that as a condition in your `if` statement:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.event.pump()
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    num_keys_pressed = len([x for x in keys_pressed if x])

    if (
        num_keys_pressed == 3
        and keys_pressed[pygame.K_LCTRL]
        and keys_pressed[pygame.K_LSHIFT]
        and keys_pressed[pygame.K_q]
    ):
        break

pygame.quit()
```